# Oracle 9i Group by offset date time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of orders which have a create_date_time (ie - 02/12/2015 14:00:44)

What I would like to do is group two months worth of orders by this create_date_time but instead of using trunc and using a proper day I'd like to go from 6am to 6am. I've tried this below but it doesn't seem to work in that way, rather it truncates and then alters the create_date_time.

```
select "Date", sum(CFS), sum(MCR) from
(select trunc(phi.create_date_Time)+6/24 as "Date",
        case when pkt_sfx = 'CFS' then sum(total_nbr_of_units)
        End as CFS,
        case when pkt_sfx <> 'CFS' then sum(total_nbr_of_units)
        end as MCR
 from pkt_hdr ph
   inner join pkt_hdr_intrnl phi
     on phi.pkt_ctrl_nbr = ph.pkt_ctrl_nbr
 where sale_grp = 'I'
 group by trunc(phi.create_date_time)+6/24, pkt_sfx
 union
 select trunc(phi.create_date_Time)+6/24 as "Date",
        case when pkt_sfx = 'CFS' then sum(total_nbr_of_units)
        End as CFS,
        case when pkt_sfx <> 'CFS' then sum(total_nbr_of_units)
        end as MCR
 from wm_archive.pkt_hdr ph
   inner join wm_archive.pkt_hdr_intrnl PHI
     on phi.pkt_Ctrl_nbr = ph.pkt_ctrl_nbr
 where sale_grp = 'I'
   and trunc(phi.create_date_time) >= trunc(sysdate)-60
 group by trunc(phi.create_date_time)+6/24, pkt_sfx
)
group by "Date"
```

Please note the union isn't necessarily important but it is required in the code as half the results will be archived but the current archive day will cause date overlap that must be removed with the outer query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just swap the ordering of `TRUNC` and adding 6h - instead of

```
select trunc(phi.create_date_Time)+6/24 as "Date"
```

use

```
select trunc(phi.create_date_Time + 6/24) as "Date"
```

(you also need to change the other occurrences of `trunc()`)

BTW: I'd use another name for the "Date" column - DATE is a SQL data type, so having a column named "Date" is somewhat confusing.

Comment: I see what you mean and this does make a difference but the bit i'm struggling with is that I'm trying to find data from 6am Friday to 6am Saturday and group that as one day, then 6am Saturday to 6am Sunday and group that as one day. My code and yours alters the date but doesn't help me to group the data correctly.

Comment: If you change every occurrence of trunc() accordingly, it should work. If not, please edit your question and add example input, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need to subtract six hours from date and then trunc this date:

```
select trunc(dt-6/24) dt, sum(units) u 
  from ( select dt, units from t1 union all
         select dt, units from t2 )
  group by trunc(dt-6/24)
```

Test:

```
create table t1 (dt date, units number(5));
insert into t1 values (timestamp '2015-12-01 12:47:00', 7);
insert into t1 values (timestamp '2015-12-01 23:47:00', 7);

create table t2 (dt date, units number(5));
insert into t2 values (timestamp '2015-12-02 05:47:00', 7);
insert into t2 values (timestamp '2015-12-02 14:47:00', 7);
```

Output:

```
Dt          U
----------  ---
2015-12-01   21
2015-12-02    7
```